# Default keyword - optional function parameter

Tags: php

When calling a PHP function with an optional parameter, how can I specify a that the optional parameter remain at it's default? Other languages have a `default` keyword that can be used - `substr($str, 0, default)`.

**Example**: `substr($str, 0, null)`

I have specified `null` as the `$length` parameter, so it will return an empty string, in actual fact I wanted the whole string.

From the `substr` documentation:

> If length is given and is **0**, **FALSE** or **NULL** an empty string will be returned.

So in this case I cannot specify `null` as I usually would, I can also not specify a number.

---

**Questions**

- What is the default value of the `$length` parameter of `substr`?
- Is there a way to specify the parameter as the default, i.e. a default keyword/operator?

---

**Real Example**:

I want to extract the host name from a poorly formatted URL.

```
$url = 'example.com';

if(!$host = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST))
{
    //There is no URL protocol so parse_url won't work
    $host = substr($url, 0, strpos($url, '/') ?: null);
}

echo $host;
```

In the above example `$host` is an empty string, because `$url` does not contain any forward slashes (`/`). If you add a slash to the end of `$url` then it works fine (`$url = 'example.com/'`).

I realize that I could merely use an `if` clause instead of a ternary, but I wondered if there was any way to send a default parameter instead of `null`.

Comment: Unfortunately I am unable to access the PHP documentation at this time, Google reports malware infestation. Instead I have been refering to my IDE docs, so I hope the answer was non obvious.

Comment: Did you accessed the docs by the Google Search? It happened to me too so I just put the docs addreess directly on address bar.

Comment: `If length is omitted, the substring starting from start until the end of the string will be returned.`

Comment: @JasonOOO, I know and that's what I want to do (have the full string). But I also want to specify the `$length` parameter as it's default value.

Comment: It seems no one really understands what I mean, I have edited the question to clarify (hopefully). There are other ways I can accomplish this, I was just wondering about it, no real issue.

Comment: if i get it now correctly [hopefully :)] you need to keep the default value of a parameter of a function when calling it? so the best way is to NOT send any parameter
ex: substr($str,0)

Comment: @Drahcir: no need to specify that! just leave it

Comment: @JasonOOO Yes, but I was just wondering if there was a special keyword that I could use in place of null. Doesn't matter really i suppose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use something like this:

```
 $host = substr($url, 0, strpos($url, '/') ?: strlen($url));
```

[strlen() function in manual](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php)

Full answer for your question is NO, PHP does not have any predefined constant to default value. Link to manual with [predefined constants](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php).

But you can define value depends on function you use like strlen() for substr()  $lenght parameter.

Also you can call function depending on parameters via call_user_func_array()

For example with substr():

```
<?php
    $url = 'example.com/123';
    $params = array($url, 0);
    $tmp = strpos($url, '/') ? strpos($url, '/'): null;
    if(!is_null($tmp))
        array_push($params ,$tmp);

    $result = call_user_func_array('substr', $params );

    var_dump($result);
```

Live example [here](http://codepad.org/NmCCeFNU)

Comment: Thanks, it would work, but it doesn't really answer the question.

Answer (score -1):

PHP docs also gives me malware alert. But worry not, for there is also w3schools: http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_substr.asp

According to the website:

> length
>
> Optional. Specifies the length of the returned string. **Default is to
>   the end of the string**.

Comment: I wanted to post w3fools blabla thingy, but then i realised there is no other option which explains it well enough with php.net down :(.

Comment: Thanks, but I wanted to send the default parameter. e.g. `substr($str, 0, default)`. PHP has a `default` keyword, but this is for switch statements.

Comment: @Drahcir wht should be the length of default?

Comment: @Joke_Sense10, I don't understand your question, default is not a number.

Answer (score -1):

if this is what you are asking

```
function myfunc($para1,$optional_para = null){
     //do stuff
}
```

so both myfunc($para) and myfunc($para,$optional) are valid

Comment: Thanks, but no, this is not what I was asking.